# Unit roots group is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}\left[\frac{1}{p}\right]$ in a field of characteristic $p\ge0$

Tags: galois-theory, cyclic-groups, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

> Let $K$ be a field so that the group of all unit roots of all orders $\mu_\infty=\bigcup_n {\mu_n}$ (where $\mu_n=\{x\in K\mid x^n=1\}$) splits on $K$. If $K$ is of characteristic $0$, take $p=1$; otherwise, $p=\operatorname{char} K$. Show that $\mu_\infty$ is non-canonically isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}\left[1/p\right]$.

In the case of complex numbers, I see that the first isomorphism theorem given that for $\phi:\Bbb{Q}\to S^1,\phi(\theta)=e^{2\pi i\theta}$, we have $\Bbb{Q}/\operatorname{ker}\phi=\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}≅\mu_\infty$. Can someone help find a generalization of this homomorphism?

Comment: In a field $K$ of characteristic $p$ there can only be a single root of $x^p-1$. Meaning that the first assumption you listed excludes positive characteristics, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}\left[\frac{1}{p}\right] \cong\bigcup_{n\ge 1} \frac1{p^n-1}\Bbb{Z}/\Bbb{Z}\cong \bigcup_{n\ge 1}\Bbb{F}_{p^n}^\times$$

Comment: slick and economical

Comment: Can anyone explain this answer with a bit more details?

Comment: @RoyShtoyerman There are two isomorphisms, the first one follows from $p\nmid m \implies m | p^{\phi(m)}-1$. The second one follows from that $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}^\times$ (the finite field with $p^n$ elements) is cyclic with $p^n-1$ elements. To make the isomorphism concrete you need to take a compatible sequence of generators of the $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}^\times$.